# Package name & Class Name of facebook app in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, facebook-android-sdk, flutter-facebook-login

I want to add the Facebook app event in my Android and IOS application develop using flutter.

[image: Facebook app image requirement]

Android: It's asking for the name of the activity which will be going to use for the deep- link with the Android application. I will go notify the app events to Facebook on various screens of flutter. Now my concern is which activity or class file name should be added here in case of the flutter?
As per the manifest file, MainActivity is the activity that will go call first in the android but without any changes in that file, can I use it directly for deep-linking on Facebook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to add `your.package.name.MainActivity` there.